# Make footer under cover sized image

Tags: html, css, footer

I am making a website and I stumbled upon a little problem.
I have the image set to be to height: 100% and width; and background-size: cover;

Is there any way I can make the footer appear so that you scroll UNDER the image?

```css
.bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("./Resources/home_bg.jpg");

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML code looks like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="bg"></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: To be clear,  I want to have an image on the website (already done), then add a footer UNDER that image.

Comment: Do you mean making your footer sticky or fixed at bottom?

Comment: Yes, I want it fixed at the bottom of the page. I watched a tutorial on that, but tit was just layered ON TOP if the image.

Comment: You'll want to be sure the z-index of the image is higher than the z-index of the footer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you only need to add a `z-index` to your divs.

The `footer` would have the smaller number `z-index`, while `.bg` is the larger one.

Also, I added a container and gave the footer a background color to just show the effect that I think you're going for.

```css
.bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/400x400");

  /* Full height */
  height: 100vh;

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

footer {
  background: #ff0000;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 8;
 }
 
 .container {
 height: 105vh;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg">BG</div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```